# Jquery form submit on loaded content not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Here is my question. I have an ajax submitted form that works perfectly fine, I have this link that takes me to that page again with ajax loaded content, but when is loaded with ajax it doesn't work.

I have this code

```
$('#uploadForm').on('change','#file-upload',function(){
$(this).submit();
});
```

The thing is to change to something like this I have tried to change to 
this

```
$('body').on('change','#file-upload',function(){
$(this).submit();
});
```

or

```
$('body').on('change','#file-upload, #uploadForm',function(){
$(this).submit();
});
```

But it doesn't work

hope you can help me, Thanks

Comment: Can you please make your question clear as well as your code?

Comment: The thing is that i load the form via ajax, but i don´t know how to make it work for submitting the form because the jquery don´t recognize the "on change" value because it has to be attached to the "body" element, i have tried all the possibilities given by jquery page and i have searched all possibilities to make it work with the same code. Here my question again. How to submit a form loaded by ajax. It´s a file upload form.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you i have changed the beginning of the form to

```
$(document).on('submit', '#uploadForm', function(e) {
    //ajax form HERE
});
```

and the trigger too.

```
$(document).on('change','#file-upload',function(){
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Thank you hope this helps to someone.